# How to check the sub nodes in ObjectListView when a head node is checked

Tags: c#, .net, objectlistview

```
 var branch = TreeListViewAccount.TreeModel.GetBranch(TreeListViewAccount.SelectedObject);
 var childs = branch.Children.Cast<SecurityObject>().ToList();
 TreeListViewAccount.SelectObject(childs.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == soft.Id));
```

This is a code you have posted as an answer to some question, but when i tried this it shows error on `SecurityObjects` and `soft`. Actually my question is how can we make an `ObjectListView` with checkboxes check all the sub nodes when a head node is checked and vice versa can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Set `HierarchicalCheckBoxes` to `true`. [Read this](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/blog7.html) for more info.